# MySQL Table Inheritance

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 type of users. Member, Moderator and Admin. Every user type has a username and password and Members only have a username and password. I keep the common data in the users table and relate the other two tables with a shared primary key.

```
users -> id, username, password, type;
moderators -> id, mod_data;
admins -> id, admin_data;
```

Is this the preferred way of handling this? Or should I create another table for members to just store their Ids and get rid of the type column? Like this:

```
users -> id, username, password;
members -> id
moderators -> id, mod_data;
admins -> id, admin_data;
```

Comment: I'd consider one common table. A user can become a moderator, or become admin - and go back, etc.

Comment: I'd prefer to have one table only. `(id, username, password, mod_data, admin_data)`. If xxx_data is NULL then the user have no according role.